# Display the contents in reverse order

Tags: c++

The code below was suggested to me by a fellow overflower. So the credits are not mine. I was trying to fidget around this code and try to print out the elements in reverse order. So far the elements are printed out starting from the start word which is dog. But the goal is to print it going the other way. starting with cat. So essentially the code works it way back words based on ancestry per say. For example in this case we got cat from cag which is the ancestor and cag's ancestor was cog. And so on so forth until we started with dog

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> dictionary;
    vector<pair<string, int>> words; //stores (word, predecessor)
    string startWord = "dog";
    string endWord = "cat";

    unordered_set<string> seenWords;

    dictionary.push_back("dog");
    dictionary.push_back("bog");
    dictionary.push_back("cog");
    dictionary.push_back("fog");
    dictionary.push_back("cat");
    dictionary.push_back("bag");
    dictionary.push_back("beg");
    dictionary.push_back("bet");
    dictionary.push_back("bat");


    words.emplace_back(startWord, -1);
    seenWords.insert(startWord);

    bool found = false;

    //Try all new words as reference words
    for(int i = 0; i < words.size() && !found; ++i) {       
        //we look for words that we can generate from words[i]
        cout << i << " " << words[i].first << ":   ";

        //try all the words from the dictionary
        for (int j = 0; j < dictionary.size(); j++) {
            string& candidate = dictionary[j];
            //check if candidate can be generated from reference

            //count the different characters
            int differentCharacters = 0;
            for (int pos = 0; pos < words[i].first.size(); ++pos)
            {
                if (candidate[pos] != words[i].first[pos])
                    ++differentCharacters;
            }
            if (differentCharacters == 1 && seenWords.find(candidate) == seenWords.end()) {
                //yes, we can generate this candidate from word[i] and we haven't seen the word before
                cout << "(" << words.size() << ")" << candidate << " ";                         

                words.emplace_back(candidate, i);
                seenWords.insert(candidate);

                if (candidate == endWord) {
                    found = true;
                    cout << "Found endword";
                    break;
                }
            }           
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    if (found) {
        //traverse the word path from the end word back to the start word
        int i = words.size() - 1;
        stack<string> wordPath;
        while (i != -1) {
            //push the current word onto a stack
            wordPath.push(words[i].first);
            //go to the previous word
            i = words[i].second;
        }

        //now retrieve the words from the stack and print them in reverse order
        cout << "Word path:" << endl;
        while (!wordPath.empty()) {
            cout << wordPath.top() << " ";
            wordPath.pop();
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: what's the question ?

Comment: _But the goal is to print it going the other way._ Use one more `stack` to reverse `wordPath`?

Comment: How can I display the current elements in reverse order?

Comment: could you help with that? I can make the stack but where do i add it in this code and include the indexes of the elements as well? @user3365922

Comment: The 'problem' here with using a `stack` is that you can **only** access the last element added (the top); there is no available `[]` operator for `std::stack`, by design. Using the less restrictive `std::vector` allows more flexibility when retrieving & displaying the contents.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite straightforward! Rather than using a `stack` to push then pop your "found" strings path, just use a `vector` and `push_back` the strings; then you can print the values off in either order! In this code, I've switched to the 'other' order from what you had:

```
if (found) {
    //traverse the word path from the end word back to the start word
    int i = words.size() - 1;
/// stack<string> wordPath;
    vector<string> wordPath;
    while (i != -1) {
        // push the current word into a vector ...
///     wordPath.push(words[i].first);
        wordPath.push_back(words[i].first);
        //go to the previous word
        i = words[i].second;
    }
    // now retrieve the words from the vector and print them ...
    cout << "Word path:" << endl;
/// while (!wordPath.empty()) {
///     cout << wordPath.top() << " ";
///     wordPath.pop();
/// }
    ///
    for (size_t w = 0; w < wordPath.size(); ++w) {
        string text = wordPath[w];
        size_t index = 0;
        for (index = 0; index < dictionary.size(); ++index) {
            if (text == dictionary[index]) break;
        }
        cout << text << "[" << index << "] ";
    }
    ///
    cout << endl;
}
```

You could even put a choice in here! To print in ***your*** original (= 'reverse') order, just change the `for` loop:

```
    for (size_t w = wordPath.size() - 1; w <= 0 ; --w) {
        cout << wordPath[w] << " ";
    }
```

Comment: the index for the words we are pushing into wordpath vector. and have them displayed along with the last cout statement that prints them in inverse order

Comment: I think so... could we try it out?

Comment: So i got the modifications in the right place. only thing is that the indexes are wrong. I get a different number for the initial word which should be at index 0. And i also get core dumped

Comment: @Elchavo18 Oops! Forget my previous edit, and the code modifications (it was wrong on so many levels, actually). Look at the latest change to the `for` loop - just determine the index while outputting the strings!

Comment: With this, I get the last line of output as: `cat[4] bat[8] bag[5] bog[1] dog[0]` - these look like the **correct** indexes to me. (Indexes of each string in `dictionary`).

Comment: @Elchavo18 What do you think the indexes should be?

Comment: So the dictionary provided was a sample dictionary. And part of a sample code that modified with an even bigger dictionary and the indexes on my end with my bigger dictionary don't match. Ill have to see what the problem is maybe i have a typo in the code. But i do gladly appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `.rbegin(), .rend()` and a reverse_iterator to step backwards through `dictionary` and a flag to start printing when `"cat"` is reached. See [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main () {

    bool prn = false;
    std::vector<std::string> dictionary;

    dictionary.push_back("dog");
    dictionary.push_back("bog");
    dictionary.push_back("cog");
    dictionary.push_back("fog");
    dictionary.push_back("cat");
    dictionary.push_back("bag");
    dictionary.push_back("beg");
    dictionary.push_back("bet");
    dictionary.push_back("bat");

    /* output in reverse order beginning with cat */
    for (auto it = dictionary.rbegin(); it != dictionary.rend(); it++) {
        if (*it == "cat")
            prn = true;
        if (prn)
            std::cout << *it << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

If I understand and you simply want to print in reverse order beginning with `"cat"`, then the following should match what you are attempting to do:

```
$ ./bin/reverse_cats
cat
fog
cog
bog
dog
```

**Outputting the Associated Vector Index**

If you want to output the vector index along with the string, you can use `dictionary.rend() - it - 1` to obtain the zero-based index, e.g.

```
    /* output in reverse order beginning with cat */
    for (auto it = dictionary.rbegin(); it != dictionary.rend(); it++) {
        if (*it == "cat")
            prn = true;
        if (prn)
            std::cout << dictionary.rend() - it - 1 << " " << *it << '\n';
    }
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/reverse_cats
4 cat
3 fog
2 cog
1 bog
0 dog
```

Comment: how can we add on there indexes?

Comment: Um..... you lost me "add on" to the indexes? If you add additional elements to the vector, then the same approach would work regardless (so long as you want to start with `"cat"`). If you want a second `std::vector`, you can simply `.push_back()` in reverse order using the same logic above.

Comment: So each of those elements have an index in the vector? How do i display them next to the element in the output?

Comment: I think OP want to list the 'found' connections, not the original `dictionary`.

Comment: Oh, I think I get what you are asking, what the index would be, yes, I'll drop an edit.